# Can't receive serial port data on 14.04

Tags: networking

I'm attempting to use a serial port testing procedure documented in the link below that uses minicom, a null modem cable, and two ubuntu 14.04 machines with the cable connected to /dev/ttyS0 on both machines.  I get no errors during the procedure however, once connected, I see no data echoed in either minicom terminal.

I get the same issue when attempting to use the Java Serialio.com libraries.  No errors occur during connection or transmit, however no data is received on the opposite port.  I did notice that the transmit buffer was filling but not being emptied.

I see no errors in syslogd.

Thanks for any help in advance.

http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2008/04/10/how-to-test-serial-ports-under-debian-linux/

Comment: What baud rate are you using? Did you try using screen? e.g. *sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600*

Comment: My test was with the default baud rate of 115200.   I only used minicom.  FYI, I'm not attempting to shell into the host using serial, I just want to validate that the serial ports are working.   The vendor of the box has only tested serial ports via windows so they are now testing with linux and suspect a BIOS tweek may be required.

Comment: I recently had the issue that minicom/screen were connecting to the bios through 115200 baud, but as soon as the kernel started booting, swtiched to 9600. You might want to give it a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is because terminal programs like minicom do not echo things they receive.  If you want to see what you type on the sender, you need to enable local echo or connect to something on the other end that is actually useful, such as a getty/login instance, rather than another client terminal.

Comment: Sorry if my original post was not clear.  By "echo", I mean that my typing on minicom 1 is not showing up on minicom 2 and visa versa.  I have two linux hosts running minicom each connected to /dev/ttyS0 on each host and a null modem cable linking to the ports

Comment: @PaulGlenn, ahh... so you have no data transferring at all then?  The term 'echo' means you see what you type on the terminal where you type it.  Are you sure that you have a null modem cable and not just a regular one with the same gender on both sides?  If you have a volt meter you can check by measuring the voltage on pins 2 and 3.  The transmitter will measure -5 to -20 volts and the other will measure zero.  The transmitter of one needs to connect to the receiver of the other end.  You might also try disabling flow control, which could account for the buffer filling and not emptying.